# How to read events for a particular date from native calendar

Tags: android

Im trying to read native calender events from my app(ICS and above) but sometimes it works and some times it shows some incorrect values.Currently i'm using this piece of code can anyone please tell me where i'm going wrong..

```
Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/instances/when").buildUpon();
    long now = new Date().getTime();
    ContentUris.appendId(builder, now);
    ContentUris.appendId(builder, now + DateUtils.YEAR_IN_MILLIS);





    Cursor eventCursorr = cr.query(builder.build(),
            new String[] { "title", "begin","description"}, "Calendars._id=" + calID,
            null, "startDay ASC, startMinute ASC"); 

    while (eventCursorr.moveToNext()) {
        final String titler = eventCursorr.getString(0).trim();
        final Date beginr = new Date(eventCursorr.getLong(1));
        final String descriptionr = eventCursorr.getString(2).trim();



        SimpleDateFormat sdfrr = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        String stimesr = sdfrr.format(beginr);


 System.out.println("titler "+titler +"stimesr "+stimesr +"descriptionr "+descriptionr );






    }





}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it guys.

```
//StartTime 
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
Date dateCC = formatter.parse("04/27/2013");
Calendar calendarStartDate = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(dateCC);

//EndTime
SimpleDateFormat formatterr = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss");

Calendar endOfDay = Calendar.getInstance();
Date dateCCC = formatterr.parse("04/27/2013 23:59:59");
endOfDay.setTime(dateCCC);

Cursor eventCursorr = cr.query(l_eventUri,
    new String[] {
    "title", "dtstart", "dtend"
}, "(" + dtstart + ">" + after + " and " + dtend + "<" + endOfDay.getTimeInMillis() + ")",
    null, "dtstart ASC");

while (eventCursorr.moveToNext()) {
    final String titler = eventCursorr.getString(0).trim();
    final Date beginr = new Date(eventCursorr.getLong(1));
    final String descriptionr = eventCursorr.getString(2).trim();

}
```

Comment: Are you getting exact out put for this?

Comment: just pass 1 weeks date eg- set 11/13/2013 in dateCC and 20/13/2013 in dateCCC you should get all the events.

Comment: calendar.setTime(dateCC); which reference is this calendar? I am getting error here

Comment: Date dateCC = formatter.parse("11/13/2013"); and Date dateCCC = formatterr.parse("20/13/2013 23:59:59"); i've tried this for one day just try for 1 week it should work i guess.

Comment: I tried but error in Date dateCC = formatter.parse("04/27/2013"); and wat is dtstart ? after? dtend?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41086/discussion-between-deepak-and-srikanth-gr)

Comment: wat is dtstart ? after? dtend?